# TypeError: User is not a constructor - Mongoose Node.js Express-Validator

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I got this error:

> "User is not a constructor TypeError"

I couldn't find out what is wrong in the code. Any advice is appreciated!!

**routes/users.js**

```
// Initialised user.js into users.js
// var User = require('../models/user');

if (errors) {
    // code here is working
} else {
    console.log('PASSED'); // logs "passed" msg successfully
    var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        password: password2
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You had been succesfully registered! Try signin.');
    res.redirect('/users/signin');
}
```

**models/user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var UserScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    phone: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.export = mongoose.model('User', UserScheme);

// encrypting password into hash
module.export.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
};
```

I can update the post if more code is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `module.export` to `module.exports`

[node docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut) * note that exports is a shortcut that points to module.exports. module.exports is the default object that gets returned when the module is required. In your example you have created a new property of module that is called export. [here is a blog post](https://blog.tableflip.io/the-difference-between-module-exports-and-exports/) that describes the relationship of exports and module.exports.

consider the following example:

```
stack: cat ./49275169.js
console.log('export', module.export)
console.log('exports', module.exports)

stack: node ./49275169.js 
export undefined
exports {}

stack:
```

here is a mongoose example:

```
stack: cat module.js 

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const schema = new Schema({ name: String })
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', schema)

module.exports.createUser = function (newUser, callback) {
  console.log(new User({ name: 'Rohit' }))
}

stack: cat ./49275169.js 

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./module')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')

const user = new User({
  name: 'Branford'
})

user.save((err, doc) => {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  mongoose.connection.close()
  return console.log(doc)
})

User.createUser()

stack: node ./49275169.js 

{ name: 'Rohit', _id: 5aa9138819d660182938b128 }
{ name: 'Branford', _id: 5aa9138819d660182938b127, __v: 0 }
stack:
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just a beginner. now i understand why it was saying "TypeError" :) cheers.